# "Workspace Currently in Use" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I normally only use Eclipse just to code in Java for class, but today I decided to use it for my own personal projects.  I didn't download anything funky and essentially only used FileWriter, java.util, java.io, and ArrayLists.

Suddenly, after running some code, I was told that Eclipse was no longer responding and had to force quit the program.

Afterward, I couldn't open Eclipse again because the workspace was currently in use.

I've looked up this problem numerous times, and what a lot of people were saying was to end Eclipse through the Task Manager and then go into the metadata file and then delete the .lock file, which I did.  However, every time I opened Eclipse again, the program would load up, but there would be no workspace for me to work on.  I'd try clicking the icon again, and now the "workspace was currently in use" window would pop up, and I'd go and see that the .lock file had reappeared in the metadata file, again, even though I'd deleted it.

I read somewhere else that another option was to relocate the metadata file, open and close Eclipse, and then overwrite the new metadata file, and it still hasn't worked, considering the .lock file ends up in the metadata again, somehow.

Is there any way I can fix this or am I just better off reinstalling Eclipse?

Thank you for any help, and sorry if this is very simple—I'm still very new to all this!

Comment: Reboot to ensure the old one is gone.

Comment: Eclipse creates the .lock file when it starts if it is not present. It is not a problem that it exists. Eclipse asks the OS for exclusive access to the .lock file, which is how it checks for 'workspace in use'. Eclipse not terminating normally can leave the file locked.

Comment: kill instances of java or eclipse and then start fresh

Comment: Where is this workspace? It's not on a network drive, is it?